# Flash Twitter API with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, actionscript-3, flash, twitter

I have read a lot about parsing JSON with Actionscript. Originally it was said to use this library.  http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/   but it seems Flash Player 11 has native support for it now.

My problem is that I cannot find examples or help that takes you from beginning to end of the process. Everything I have read seems to start in the middle. I have no real experience with JSON so this is a problem. I don't even know how to point ActionScript to the JSON file it needs to read.

I have a project with a tight deadline that requires me to read twitter through JSON. I need to get the three most recent tweets, along with the user who posted it, their twitter name and the time those tweets were posted.

The back end to this is already set up I believe by the development team here, therefor my JSON files or XML just needs to be pointed to and then I need to display the values in the interface text boxes I have already designed and created.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...I do know that there are a lot of threads on here I just do not understand them as they all have some understanding of it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Load the data, whatever it is.
2. Parse the data from a particular format.

For this you would normally:

1. Use `URLLoader` class to load any data. (Just go to the language reference and look into example of how to use this class).
2. Use whatever parser to parse the particular format that you need. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html this is the reference to JSON API, it also shows usage examples. I'm not aware of these API being in production version of the player, still there might be quite a bit of FP 10.X players out there, so I'd have a fallback JSON parser, but I would recommend using this library: http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/ over as3corelib because it is faster. The built-in API are no different from those you would find in browser, so if you look up JSON JavaScript entries, the use should be in general similar to Flash.

After you parse JSON format, you will end up with a number of objects of the following types: Object, Array, Boolean, Number, String. It has also literals to mean `null` and `undefined`. Basically, you will be working with native to Flash data structures, you only should take extra care because they will be dynamically constructed, meaning you may not make assumption about existence of parts of the data - you must always check the availability.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Loading the data is easy, I know that much at least thank goodness. The version of flash probably doesn't matter since we will have control over the environment this will be displayed in.

Unfortunately I do not know how to even parse at this point. I've read Adobe's docs several times and have no idea what they are talking about :S Do you know of any simplified versions I can read step by step. I find Adobe's docs confusing more than helpful most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

wvxvw's answer is good, but I think skips over a to be desired explanation of what JSON itself is.  JSON is plain text, javascript object notation, when you read the text on screen it looks something like this

http://www.json.org/example.html

you can see a side by side JSON and XML (both plain text formats) essentially JSON is a bunch of name value pairs.

When you use JSON.parse("your JSON string goes here") it will do the conversions to AS3 "dynamic objects" which are just plain objects (whose properties can be assigned without previously being defined, hence dynamic).  But to make a long story short, take the example you see in the link above, copy and paste the JSON as a string variable in AS3, use

```
        var str:String = '{"glossary": {"title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {"title": "S","GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}';
        var test:Object = JSON.parse(str);
```

method on the string, store it in a variable and use the debugger to see what the resulting object is.  As far as I know there's really nothing else to JSON it's simply this format for storing data (you can't use E4X on it since it's not XML based and because of that it's slightly more concise than XML, no closing tags, but in my opionion slightly less readable... but is valid javascript).  For a nice break-down of the performance gains/losses between AMF, JSON and XML check out this page: http://www.jamesward.com/census2/ Though many times you don't have a choice with regard to the delivery message format or protocol being used if you're not building the service, it's good to understand what the performance costs of them are.